# How to display root directories for a domain with DFS?

Tags: filesystems, dfs

I am working with a DFS setup of the standard form \\domain.local\root. We are sharing these and to navigate to the DFS share users would type \\domain\sales or \\domain\support. **How can I setup so that users can type \\domain and see all available root folders?** Currently if a user types in \\domain a dialog with Windows cannot access window.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the netbios form of your domain `\\domain` goes nowhere, but The FQDN version of your domain `\\example.org` will always point to your Domain controllers.  So if you want your DFS roots to show up the DNS version of your domain, your need to have **all** your Domain controllers host DFS root servers.  You can of course create folder targets below your root, that points to other file servers.

Comment: I always run DFS-N on domain controllers, easier way of life (by visibility) and the fact that domain controllers are rarely unavailable.

Comment: How can I suppress domain users from seeing the SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares then? I want to avoid confusing people with these unknown shares.

Comment: AFAIK, You cannot.  Those shares are required.